# How do I infinitely repeat a sequence in Kotlin?

Tags: collections, kotlin, sequence

I want to infinitely repeat `T` elements in a `Sequence<T>`. This can't be done using [kotlin.collections.asSequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html). For example:

```
val intArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val finiteIntSequence = intArray.asSequence()
val many = 10
finiteIntSequence.take(many).forEach(::print)
// 123
```

This is not what I want. I expected some kind of `kotlin.collections.repeat` function to exist, but there isn't, so I implemented one myself (e.g. for this `IntArray`):

```
var i = 0
val infiniteIntSequence = generateSequence { intArray[i++ % intArray.size] }
infiniteIntSequence.take(many).forEach(::print)
// 1231231231
```

This is quite imperative, so I feel there must be a more functional and less verbose way to do this. If it exists, what is/are Kotlin's standard way(s) to repeat collections / arrays a(n) (in)finite amount of times?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Update: coroutines are no longer experimental as of Kotlin 1.3! Use them as much as you like :)

---

If you allow the use of [coroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-coroutines) you can do this in a pretty clean way using [`sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sequence.html):

> an infinite amount of times

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.repeat() = sequence { while (true) yieldAll(this@repeat) }
```

Note the use of a [qualified `this` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified) `this@repeat` - simply using `this` would refer to the lambda's receiver, a [`SequenceScope`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence-scope/index.html).

then you can do

```
val intArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val finiteIntSequence = intArray.asSequence()
val infiniteIntSequence = finiteIntSequence.repeat()

println(infiniteIntSequence.take(10).toList())
// ^ [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

> a finite amount of times

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.repeat(n: Int) = sequence { repeat(n) { yieldAll(this@repeat) } }
```

Comment: Or `repeat(n) { yieldAll(...) } `

Comment: @voddan Thanks, this is definitely cleaner and arguably more readable :)

Comment: I'm accepting this as coroutines are the way to go since their stable release, although they do require an extra dependency. Edit: not sure if an extra dependency is needed, though, because `sequence` comes from here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sequence.html

Comment: @Erik yep, sequence builders are part of the standard library now. IIRC `kotlinx.coroutines` mostly contains utilities (such as `await` extensions for various types of futures).

Answer (score 5):

To avoid using the experimental coroutines, use:

```
generateSequence { setOf("foo", 'b', 'a', 'r') }
  .flatten() // Put the Iterables' contents into one Sequence
  .take(5) // Take 5 elements
  .joinToString(", ")

// Result: "foo, b, a, r, foo"
```

or alternatively, if you want to repeat the entire collection a number of times, just take before flattening:

```
generateSequence { setOf("foo", 'b', 'a', 'r') }
  .take(5) // Take the entire Iterable 5 times
  .flatten() // Put the Iterables' contents into one Sequence
  .joinToString(", ")

// Result: "foo, b, a, r, foo, b, a, r, foo, b, a, r, foo, b, a, r, foo, b, a, r"
```

For the original question's `IntArray`, the array first must be converted to an `Iterable<Int>` (otherwise `flatten()` isn't available):

```
val intArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)

generateSequence { intArray.asIterable() }
  .flatten()
  .take(10)
  .joinToString(", ")

// Result: "1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1"
```

Furthermore, other types of `Array`, e.g. `ByteArray` or `LongArray`, as well as `Map` are not `Iterable`, but they all implement the `asIterable()` method like `IntArray` in the example above.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is pretty clear:

```
generateSequence(0) { (it + 1) % intArray.size }
        .map { intArray[it] }
        .forEach { println(it) }
```

Comment: Your answer can be used to generate a sequence of `Int` values, but I'm interested in repeating an arbitrary collection or array of any type, e.g. Collection<Person>. By default, there is no `Person.plus(other: Number)`, so this is not the answer I'm looking for. This is what I intended to say with the first sentence of my question: I want to repeat a collection or array of any type `T` infinitely.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry I misinterpreted your answer! You're right, this is generic and doesn't require coroutines, which is a great alternative for the Mango's answer. Thanks, have my upvote.

Comment: Still, I think the Kotlin standard lib should contain some kind of `repeat()` and `repeat(times: Int)` methods.

Comment: Added another more generic answer

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure if this is due to API changes in Kotlin, but it's possible to do the following:

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.repeatForever() =
  generateSequence(this) { it }.flatten()
```

Live example: https://pl.kotl.in/W-h1dnCFx

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this is basically a less verbose version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48024169/3169029), but using an extension and using `flatMap` instead of `flatten`. Example: https://pl.kotl.in/EbpEdBT6W

Comment: Good point, I forgot about flatten, I'll update. However, using this creates a `GeneratorSequence` instead of relying on an infinite loop and coroutines for it which I'm not sure about efficiency but at the very least, having a `while(true)` sounds some alarms on my head (probably unfounded though)

Comment: Note that I referred to a different answer than the one containing infinite loops!

Comment: Also note that using infinite loops in sequence generation where the loop contains `yield` or `yieldAll` is not necessarily alarming, because these functions are suspending and will therefore only loop forever if polled forever. Unless the infinite loops contain other 'dangerous' (e.g. computationally heavy) code, they are safe to use.

Answer (score 2):

A generic solution would be to reuse the proposal from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48007547/8073652) with extension functions:

```
fun <T> Array<T>.asRepeatedSequence() =
        generateSequence(0) {
            (it + 1) % this.size
        }.map(::get)

fun <T> List<T>.asRepeatedSequence() =
        generateSequence(0) {
            (it + 1) % this.size
        }.map(::get)
```

Called like this:

```
intArray.asRepeatedSequence().forEach(::println)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have Guava on your classpath, you can do the following:

```
val intArray = intArrayOf(1, 2, 3)
val cyclingSequence = Iterators.cycle(intArray.asList()).asSequence()

// prints 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1
println(cyclingSequence.take(10).joinToString(","))
```